# Showing definition for second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is two-times differentiable at $x$. Show that

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2} = f''(x).
$$

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%5Clim_%7Bh%5Cto+0%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bf(x%2Bh)+-+2f(x)+%2B+f(x-h)%7D%7Bh%5E2%7D+%3D+f%27%27(x)).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the Taylor expansion
$$f(x\pm h)=f(x)\pm hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+o(h^2)$$